# Azure Front Door: Authentication header with bearer token not passed through

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

Azure Front Door doesn't forward the Authorization header bearer token to the endpoint. All other headers are passed along fine except this one.

Standard headers (such as Accept) are passed through, made-up headers (such as 'OtherHeader') are passed through as well, while key-based security headers (such as 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key') are also passed through fine.

The routing rules are set to perform a 302 (Found) Redirect as we're performing IP filtering at the endpoint and this type of routing helps with that.

Is there a way to tell Front Door to pass through the authorization header on the redirect call in the same way that it's passing other headers?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Front Door can't pass the request header to the new request.
If it returns a 302 response, the client is the one making the request, and needs to set the header.

Comment: But it is passing along all other headers on the original request