# Why does front door remove Authorization Headers when we do a Redirect?

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I have a set of APIs built using web service (legacy) and I have created a new set of APIs using Azure functions. Now I want all my legacy API to route to Azure Function.

I tried the Azure Front Door service redirect to achieve the functionality. I was able to redirect but the request headers are missing in the redirected requests. Not sure why Azure Front Door is removing them?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question should have your effort to solve the task. Try to focus on details. Code is good, environment, screenshots, error codes if any. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57905872/azure-front-door-authentication-header-with-bearer-token-not-passed-through